# What is full service / interim service / service a / service b?

Tags: service

I have been trying to book the car for service as the panel suggests that 'service B is due', but the booking services offer Full service an Interim service to choose from. I guess Service B is one of them, but which one?

Comment: You're looking at a manufacturer specific codes. Consult your mfg's documentation to interpret it.

Comment: If it's a Mercedes 2009 onwards, Service A starts at 10,000 miles, and then every 20,000 miles afterwards. Service B starts at 20,000 miles, and then every 20,000 miles afterwards (so you alternate between Service A and Service B). They're the same, except that Service B indicates a cabin filter replacement and a brake fluid exchange. A Mercedes garage would know that, but an independent might not. Just give them the service book. Both of them equate to a Full service, in my opinion.

Comment: @Pete I have spoken to a garage I have booked my car in, the guy said that B is a full service an pops us every 20,000 miles. Exactly what you said, sir.